# Crouton with more than one OS

Tags: chrome-os

ChromeOS

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Using `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -r utopic` I can install ubuntu 14.10 with the xfce interface, it says I can load it up on chromeos by running `sudo startxfce4` . But if I want to install another version, `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce -r kali` , it gives me the same exact command to run that. I can install as many OS's as I want, but how do you run the others if you install 2 OS's with xfce for example? Since I installed utopic first, that's the only one that opens.

Comment: Crouton Runs in a chroot, as such you'd need multiple chroots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)'s [`startxfce4` command](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/host-bin/startxfce4) is just a wrapper around `enter-chroot`, which has a bunch of options that let you do atypical things like you're asking for. Say `sudo enter-chroot --help` for a list.

The one you want here is `-n`, which lets you name a specific chroot. The full command would be:

```
$ sudo enter-chroot -n kali exec startxfce4
```

You could wrap that up in a shell script, but since ChromeOS's command shell remembers history, I don't bother.  I just say <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd> to start the shell, then <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to search back through the history for the big ugly command I want.

I use the ChromeOS shell — as opposed to the Ubuntu shell via Crouton — for little other than Crouton commands, so there's no danger that my carefully-composed long commands will ever fall out of the history.

Incidentally, two XFCE-based chroots are going to take a large chunk of the free space available on a typical Chromebook. You might want to store the chroots on an SD card instead of the internal storage, since most Chromebooks have a built-in SD card reader. Then you need to add something like `-c /media/removable/Crouton/chroots` to your `enter-chroot` command. (The `Crouton` part of that path is the name I've used for my SD card.)

Comment: sudo enter-chroot -c /media/removeable/Crouton/chroots -n kali exec startxfce4    ..... to run it off the sd card?

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, assuming your SD card is called `Crouton`, the chroot you want to run is called `kali`, and you actually [set the `kali` chroot up on the SD card](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#i-want-to-install-the-chroot-to-another-location). Again, run the various Crouton commands with `--help` to get an idea of all the many variations on the default functionality.

Comment: Could you just copy the contents to the sd card or you have to run a command when setting it up? what would that command be?

Comment: @aaron: It's [covered in the FAQ](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/README.md#this-chroots-namelocationpasswordexistence-sucks-how-to-fix).

Comment: I dont see it on the main page but I found a thread someone created. Unless you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The link I just gave you takes you straight to the answer: use `edit-chroot`. Say `edit-chroot --help` for instructions.